# Form Action with Relative Path Not Working

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP and MySql and running inside of VS.PHP. I have written the following:

```
<form action="../register.php" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

But when I click, nothing actually happens. Am I not allowed to use relative paths for actions?

Comment: I don't know *what* the problem is, but the relative path is not it

Comment: What do you mean with nothing happens? Does the script runs? Have you got a 404 error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

The button input type is mostly used with javascript, but will not submit your form automatically.

EDIT:

Here is a reference on the [input button tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-button-tag.htm)